# Android onSupportNavigateUp when NavHost is not in MainActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-navigation

I have an activity which holds `FragmentContainerView`. In the `FragmentContainerView` I have a `NavHostFragment`. I want to implement `onSupportNavigateUp` in the `NavHostFragment`.

```
class MenuNavHostFragment : Fragment() {
    fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController,null)
    }
}
```

in MainActivity.kt

```
private lateinit var menuNavHostFragment: MenuNavHostFragment
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return menuNavHostFragment.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

in fragment_menu_nav_host

```
...
tools:context=".View.MenuNavHostFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_menu_nav_host"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
...
```

When I press the back button, my application destroys when I want it to go back one step in the navigation stack.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

check [Update UI components with NavigationUI](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#top_app_bar)

Comment: Can you be more specific here?

Comment: if you mean physical back button, first check this `app:defaultNavHost="true"` attribute in your `NavHostFragment` as it intercepts the system back button. Both `NavController.navigateUp()` and `NavController.popBackStack()` methods does not finish your Activity

Answer (score 0):

If you want go back, use findNavController.navigateUp() function

Answer (score 0):

replace the mentioned code by the following one, according to your program:

```
 open fun navigateUp (drawerLayout: DrawerLayout, navController: NavController):Boolean {
val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)
  return navigateUp(this.drawerLayout, navController)
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.